# How to make 3 finger tap on touchpad act as middle mouse button for Debian 10, Cinnamon

Tags: debian, cinnamon, touchpad, mouse-gestures

I'm using Cinnamon on Debian 10 through virtualbox, and the "Mouse and Touchpad" settings don't seem to let me configure a 3 finger touchpad tap as the middle mouse button.

How else can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

To enable triple-finger tap , edit the configuration file under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
```

As follows:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        #MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "Tapping" "on"
        Option "TappingButtonMap" "lmr"
EndSection
```

Documented on Arch-linux wiki: [Button re-mapping](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput#Button_re-mapping)

> Swapping two- and three-finger tap for a touchpad is a straight forward example. Instead of the default three-finger tap for pasting you can configure two-finger tap pasting by setting the `TappingButtonMap` option in your Xorg configuration file. To set 1/2/3-finger taps to left/right/middle set `TappingButtonMap` to `lrm`, for left/middle/right set it to `lmr`.
>
> ```
> Section "InputClass"
>      Identifier "touchpad"
>      Driver "libinput"
>      MatchIsTouchpad "on"
>      Option "Tapping" "on"
>      Option "TappingButtonMap" "lmr"
>  EndSection
> ```
>
> **NB:** Remember to remove `MatchIsTouchpad "on"` if your device is not a touchpad and adjust the Identifier accordingly.

Comment: Well this is strange, but your text didn't work at first, so I deleted the uncommented MatchIsTouchpad and it worked. Then, because I wanted to fool around with it to understand how things worked, I changed the "lmr" to "lrm", but that didn't actually swap them for whatever reason. I then decided to change it back to "lmr", but it didn't change back to how it was working. Now I'm back to where I started, even with the edits I made to make it work previously. I'm super confused.

Comment: @Otherness Log out then login after modifying the configuration file.

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't do anything. Could it be that I'm changing the wrong configuration file perhaps?